# Save a GMail to Google Doc keeping the same appearance

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to save a email (from GMail), that has some fancy things, like different font colors and etc that can be done using GMail(And that are understood by GMail).

But when I save the email to a Doc, I see that it uses HTML(I think), so wanted to know if there is already a Google Script to convert the GMail fancy things to a Google Docs fancy thing =)

I'm new to Google Scripts, and still having some problem finding some references, so if there is already a Script for this, then could anyone tell me?

Thanks.

Comment: do you really need to have it in google doc format and be able to modify it ?    or do you just need to save and view ?

Comment: The best option would be to save it to a doc, and then modify it. just as a Google Docs, but since this seems to be a little too much for now, It's just ok to save and view it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no such script. What you can do that will probably work better is to get the emails html and send it to [Google Docs List Data API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) via UrlFetch and have it convert to the Google Documents format for you. That is probably way better than trying to do a "conversion" on the script directly.

Such script is also more likely to have been implemented already, but I haven't done it myself yet.

Comment: I see, in the end I simply created a doc with the html from the emails and then saved the doc as .html.
After that I printed it as pdf... not the best solution, but a working one too.